# Find the next vertices at the intersect line

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, geometric-network

I'm Trying to calculate the angle between two intersected lines at geometric network (simple edge)in order to check if the lines are close to be perpendicular. I already have an Array of the intersection vertices and a function that calculate the angle using Pythagorean theorem. How I can get the next vertices at the intersect line, in order to calculate the angle between this vertices and the intersect point using the function ?

Comment: Can you perhaps include a diagram of what you are after?  This seems like the third similar question that you have asked without giving much context to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm developing QA tools for geometric network for water utilities - to check the quality of the digitizer who collect the data. At my previous questions i developed a tool to check angle between vertices- steel pipes can have only a specific angles. Now I'm after the angles between lines.

Comment: See these for ideas: [1](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44065/how-to-calculate-the-incidence-angle-of-a-polyline) [2](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21038/how-to-find-the-angle-between-intersecting-features-in-two-featureclasses)

Answer (score 2):

You tag this question as a python question so assuming you are using 10.1 then looking at the page on [Polyline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polyline/018z00000008000000/) geometry in the Help file it shows that Polyline has a method called *getPart* which returns a list of points. If you know which end your intersection point is then its just a matter of stepping through the list.